# call delegate with reference type parameter visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have attached a delegate to a button's click event,
inside the delegate I call the handling function and I send it 3 parameters
1 parameter is object and 2 others is integers..

```
button1.Click += delegate { AttachToLabel( node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("message").Value, id, depend);};
```

This has worked fine under visual studio 2012
but under visual studio 2010 when I click the button I get error saying that:

> node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("message").Value is null

Now I think I understand why I get this error, because this parameter is reference type and not value type and it doesn't exist when I press the button

But why it is working in visual studio 2012??

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what is the value of node.Attributes in VS 2012? Is it different than what you see in VS 2010. How is reference type relevant in this case? ref type will be ref in both

Comment: node type is XmlNode, node.Attributes is XmlAttributesCollection and with the .Value it is a string (only if "message" is exists in that iteration)

the error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: if I will add in previous line 
string message =  node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("message").Value
and then in the delegate change to AttachToLabel(message, id, depend) then it will work also in VS2010